# Leer Texto con formato a csv

Tags: python, csv, diccionarios

Con la api de zoho consulto el correo que tenga un adjunto con este formato:

```
b' Ruta\tDespacho\tFecha Reparto\tRegional\tZona\tSector\tNombre\tTipo 
Caja\tFactura\tNumero Caja\tCodigo Cliente\tIdentificacion\tCod Premio/Producto\tDireccion\tCodigo Distrito\tDistri
to\tDescrip Premios/Productos\tCantidad\tCiudad\tTelefono\tReferencia de la Direccion\tCampana\tFecha Despacho\tCons Caja\tCodigo Distribuidor\tDistribuidor\tCelular1\n  18782\t51602\t\t
001\t132\t012\tNELLY MARIBEL TOAPANTA TOAQUIZA\tPEDIDO\t1528806\t1\t132012001\t0504095548\t\tLA VICTORIA SN ANTONIO TELLO\t81\tMULINLIVI\t\t1\tPUJILI\t0\tCASA AZUL DE 1 PISO, VIA PRINCIP
AL POR LA CURVA CERRAMIENTO MAYA PORTON NEGRO CA\t202002\t01/29/2020\t14\t135\tMARIANA ESPINOZA SANTILLAN\t0984044011\n'
```

Estoy queriendo poder convertirlo a csv y poder darle formato en el python:
Veo muchos ejemplos pero la mayoria lo hace abriendo el archivo pero no con el contenido directamente:
de esta manera:

```
import csv
with open('archivo.csv') as csvfile:
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
#y aqui poder manejarlo como diccionario
for row in reader:
    print(row['Ruta'], row['Despacho'])
```

pero no veo la manera de como pasarlo al formato csv y luego manejarlo como diccionario.

Comment: Hey Piero, ¿seguro que quieres buscar por archivos con formato de nombres? ¿Y si el usuario le pone un nombre del tipo `sdfdhfgjfg4w5345efsdg.csv` ? ¿Son correos automáticos generados en algún lado?

Comment: No tengo el nombre, solo el contenido y si se genera en un sistema aparte del cliente y solo deseo convertir el contenido ese a un archivo csv y poder trabajarlo como diccionario

Comment: Manda un DM por Twitter o Telegram, uso el mismo nick, para evitar volver un chat a la zona de los comentarios

Comment: Lo que no entiendo  es que nuestras un texto que dices quieres convertir a `csv`. ¿Te refieres a  guardar ese texto en un formato delimitado por comas?  Si es así, deberías señalar como el texto debe ser formateado. Veo que en texto existen muchos caracteres de tabulacion `\t` y caracteres de nueva línea `\n`. ¿Quieres que los tabuladores `\t` se conviertan en comas y Los `\n` se guarde como nueva línea? En todo caso, muéstranos un ejemplo de cómo sería el csv que quieres.

Comment: Ya está solucionado amigo y publique la respuesta 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno por si alguien necesita hacer algo parecido lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

Primero convertí el formato de bytes a str para poder trabajar:

```
file = file.content.decode('utf-8')
upload_raw_data = [] # En esta lista guardare la data deseada
```

Luego le hice un split a los \n para separar las filas y una función lambda \t para separar las columnas:

```
data_list = list(map(lambda row: row.split("\t"), file.split("\n")))
```

y obtenemos en este caso 3 listas de esta forma:

```
[[' Ruta', 'Despacho', 'Fecha Reparto', 'Regional', 'Zona', 'Sector', 'Nombre', 'Tipo Caja', 'Factura', 'Numero Caja', 'Codigo Cliente', 'Identificacion', 'Cod Premio/Producto', 'Direcci
on', 'Codigo Distrito', 'Distrito', 'Descrip Premios/Productos', 'Cantidad', 'Ciudad', 'Telefono', 'Referencia de la Direccion', 'Campana', 'Fecha Despacho', 'Cons Caja', 'Codigo Distrib
uidor', 'Distribuidor', 'Celular1'], ['  18782', '51602', '', '001', '132', '012', 'NELLY MARIBEL TOAPANTA TOAQUIZA', 'PEDIDO', '1528806', '1', '132012001', '0504095548', '', 'LA VICTORI
A SN ANTONIO TELLO', '81', 'MULINLIVI', '', '1', 'PUJILI', '0', 'CASA AZUL DE 1 PISO, VIA PRINCIPAL POR LA CURVA CERRAMIENTO MAYA PORTON NEGRO CA', '202002', '01/29/2020', '14', '135', '
MARIANA ESPINOZA SANTILLAN', '0984044011'], ['']]
```

En donde la primera lista, de ley, son las cabeceras y las guardo en una lista aparte para luego hacer el match con su valor:

```
headers = [header.strip() for header in data_list[0]]  # Uso el strip para quitar espacios en blanco ejm: '  valor' por 'valor'

['Ruta', 'Despacho', 'Fecha Reparto', 'Regional', 'Zona', 'Sector', 'Nombre', 'Tipo Caja', 'Factura', 'Numero Caja', 'Codigo Cliente', 'Identificacion', 'Cod Premio/Producto', 'Direccion
', 'Codigo Distrito', 'Distrito', 'Descrip Premios/Productos', 'Cantidad', 'Ciudad', 'Telefono', 'Referencia de la Direccion', 'Campana', 'Fecha Despacho', 'Cons Caja', 'Codigo Distribui
dor', 'Distribuidor', 'Celular1']
```

Y por ultimo recorro la lista (data_list) con enumerate que utilizo para tener el indice, ya que si quiero tener el indice tendría que crear un contador y no quería que se vea feo el código XD:

```
for idx, data in enumerate(data_list):
# Valido que no recorra la cabecera y que tenga la misma cantidad de elementos en la lista que los header si no no haria bien el match.
    if idx > 0 and len(data) === len(headers):
       #Como practicamente tenemos el mismo numero de elementos le asignamos su cabecera por el indice de cada elemento
        data_dict = {headers[idx_el]: el.strip() for idx_el, el in enumerate(data)}
       #Guardamos todo esto en una nueva lista con la data que se quiere :D!
       upload_raw_data.append(data_dict)
```

Dando como resultado:

```
[{'Ruta': '18782', 'Despacho': '51602', 'Fecha Reparto': '', 'Regional': '001', 'Zona': '132', 'Sector': '012', 'Nombre': 'NELLY MARIBEL TOAPANTA TOAQUIZA', 'Tipo Caja': 'PEDIDO', 'Factu
ra': '1528806', 'Numero Caja': '1', 'Codigo Cliente': '132012001', 'Identificacion': '0504095548', 'Cod Premio/Producto': '', 'Direccion': 'LA VICTORIA SN ANTONIO TELLO', 'Codigo Distrit
o': '81', 'Distrito': 'MULINLIVI', 'Descrip Premios/Productos': '', 'Cantidad': '1', 'Ciudad': 'PUJILI', 'Telefono': '0', 'Referencia de la Direccion': 'CASA AZUL DE 1 PISO, VIA PRINCIPA
L POR LA CURVA CERRAMIENTO MAYA PORTON NEGRO CA', 'Campana': '202002', 'Fecha Despacho': '01/29/2020', 'Cons Caja': '14', 'Codigo Distribuidor': '135', 'Distribuidor': 'MARIANA ESPINOZA 
SANTILLAN', 'Celular1': '0984044011'}]
```

Espero le sirva a alguien :D!

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una solucion

```py
import csv,re
origin = b'Ruta\tDespacho\tFecha Reparto\tRegional\tZona\tSector\tNombre\tTipoCaja\tFactura\tNumero Caja\tCodigo Cliente\tIdentificacion\tCod Premio/Producto\tDireccion\tCodigo Distrito\tDistrito\tDescrip Premios/Productos\tCantidad\tCiudad\tTelefono\tReferencia de la Direccion\tCampana\tFecha Despacho\tCons Caja\tCodigo Distribuidor\tDistribuidor\tCelular1\n  18782\t51602\t\t001\t132\t012\tNELLY MARIBEL TOAPANTA TOAQUIZA\tPEDIDO\t1528806\t1\t132012001\t0504095548\t\tLA VICTORIA SN ANTONIO TELLO\t81\tMULINLIVI\t\t1\tPUJILI\t0\tCASA AZUL DE 1 PISO, VIA PRINCIPAL POR LA CURVA CERRAMIENTO MAYA PORTON NEGRO CA\t202002\t01/29/2020\t14\t135\tMARIANA ESPINOZA SANTILLAN\t0984044011\n'


data = origin.decode('utf-8').splitlines()



with open("tmp.csv", "w") as csv_file:
    # Create the writer object with tab delimiter
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = '\t')
    for line in data:
        writer.writerow(re.split('\s+',line))
```

OUTPUT

```
Ruta    Despacho    Fecha   Reparto Regional    Zona    Sector  Nombre  TipoCaja    Factura Numero  Caja    Codigo  Cliente Identificacion  Cod Premio/Producto Direccion   Codigo  Distrito    Distrito    Descrip Premios/Productos   Cantidad    Ciudad  Telefono    Referencia  de  la  Direccion   Campana Fecha   Despacho    Cons    Caja    Codigo  Distribuidor    Distribuidor    Celular1
    18782   51602   001 132 012 NELLY   MARIBEL TOAPANTA    TOAQUIZA    PEDIDO  1528806 1   132012001   0504095548  LA  VICTORIA    SN  ANTONIO TELLO   81  MULINLIVI   1   PUJILI  0   CASA    AZUL    DE  1   PISO,   VIA PRINCIPAL   POR LA  CURVA   CERRAMIENTO MAYA    PORTON  NEGRO   CA  202002  01/29/2020  14  135 MARIANA ESPINOZA    SANTILLAN   0984044011
```

Comment: Muchachos gracias 